# Only null recieved when executing a command line program with Java

Tags: java, command-line, process, runtime

Okay, so I have been experimenting with the `Process` and `Runtime` classes and I have run into a problem. When I try to execute this command : `cmd /c dir`, the output is null. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
try {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = runtime.exec("cmd /c dir");

    BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    //BufferedReader serverOutputError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serverStart.getErrorStream()));

    String line = null;

    while ((output.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    int exitValue = process.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Command exited with exit value: " + exitValue);

    process.destroy();
    System.out.println("destroyed");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I get this for an output:

```
(18 lines of just "null")
Command exited with exit value: 0
destroyed
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never set your `line` variable that you are using to write to the console.

Replace

```
while ((output.readLine()) != null) {
```

with

```
while ((line = output.readLine()) != null) {
```

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
String line = output.readLine();

while (line != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    line = output.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((output.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

should be

```
while ((line = output.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = null;
while ((output.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Here is your problem. You never set line to anything in your loop. It remains null.
You need to set line to value of output.readLine().

```
while((line = output.readLine()) != null)
```